# Php set interval php function

Tags: javascript, php, setinterval

I want to use a PHP function that is equivalent to the `setInterval()` function in JavaScript.

I tried:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  <?php echo getAllRooms(); ?>
}, 2000);
```

Comment: That's not a PHP function, it's JavaScript.

Comment: yes i know but can use that or similar to work?

Comment: yes and no, you can use `sleep` but until the sleep stops running you will not see anything on the screen.  What you are looking to do is AJAX and that's more complicated.  What level of programmer in PHP and Javascript are you?

Comment: @Forbs im not a "pro" but i understand a little bit xD

Comment: then in a short answer, `getAllRooms` needs to be moved into it's own php function by itself, and it should populate an html element using 'id'.  Look up JQuery AJAX for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use PHP, you can use the PHP [`sleep`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function. **Keep in mind this is a synchronous function** unlike the JavaScript `setInterval()` function.

If you need an asynchronous function you either need to use AJAX, or `echo` a script in PHP.

```
<?php 
echo "<script>setInterval(function() {
    // Code runs after 1 second
}, 1000);
</script>";
?>
```